# Java RIA app with local database + synchronisation support

Tags: synchronization, ria, derby, jdeveloper, oracle-adf

I need to develop an ordering system for a client that works with tablet computers. Because they are not always connected, the app needs a replication of the database and the ability to synchronize with the main database on command.

Deployment to the clients should be easy and i want to use java technologies because i am familiar with Toplink EJB persistence and Glassfish as a front-end middleware for data retrieval.

I was thinking about using JDeveloper ADF for building the UI because of its ease, Derby for local storage and Glassfish or WebLogic as middleware.

- Is this a good approach of using these technologies together ?
- Should i use a framework to synchronize with the database ?
- How can deployment be automated ?

Thanx for ur help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) using JDeveloper with Derby is a good idea. you can set it up easily. following link gives information on how to do it http://tenthsense.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-apache-derby-with-jdeveloper-to.html

2) using ADF is a good idea too.. as it drastically reduces the development time. I have no idea on Glassfish, but weblogic is standard for ADF and there should be no problems if you use that. I actually tried deploying it on Tomcat, although I was successful I won't suggest as the deployment is highly unstable. But it works and its open source :-)
following link gives information on how to do it
http://tenthsense.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-apache-derby-with-jdeveloper-to.html

-hiten